# any suggestion to shorten the installation time of npm in teamcity

Tags: node.js, npm, continuous-integration, teamcity

Trying to use teamcity to build and deploy ionic program. but every time teamcity need to install all npm modules.

I tried to use powershell to back up the node_modules folder but teamsity does not allow to use remove-item or move-item in powershell and I have 4-5 agent to build project in teamcity, so I think store in local is not a better way.

Anyone have a best solution to reduce the time.

Comment: I haven't worked with ionic or teamcity. In my nodejs project, I install NPM modules with the command: `$npm install`
What I have observed is, by switching off the progress bar of NPM, the installation time is reduced significantly. `$npm set progress=false`
Not sure whether it's useful in your case, but give it a shot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes you cannot avoid running `npm install` but you can significantly speed it up.

A possible solution is to either use the npm cache:

- https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/cache
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-cache

but this is not always possible to use effectively.

Another option is to use an npm proxy:

- https://github.com/runk/npm-proxy-cache

or:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/sinopia

> sinopia - a private/caching npm repository server. It allows you to have a local npm registry with zero configuration. You don't have to install and replicate an entire CouchDB database. Sinopia keeps its own small database and, if a package doesn't exist there, it asks npmjs.org for it keeping only those packages you use.

Some good tutorials that may be helpful here:

- http://willcodefor.beer/setup-your-own-npm-cache-server/
- https://addyosmani.com/blog/using-npm-offline/
- http://thejackalofjavascript.com/maintaining-a-private-npm-registry/

Comment: This is great suggestion, I will go to read them and try to find the best way. I would not choose npm-cache, maybe sinopia or npm-proxy-cache.

Comment: if  teamcity will randomly assign agent, the npm-proxy-cache also does not work, unless u can create a npm-proxy-cache in one server and all npm install will fetch packages from that single server.